# In Betrayal, does a monster really die after 1 hit?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

We're playing betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill. If I read the rules correctly, when a player hits a monster, even just for one damage, he defeats it and the monster gets stunned. In my version of the haunt, it even gets killed right away. This is for haunt 46

So that means if the monster (4 might) wins against the hero (4 might, 4 speed), say with a 2 point difference, the player loses 2 physical points (4 might, 2 speed). The monster needs to repeat this 3 more times to finish off the player.

On the other hand, if the hero wins against the monster, the monster is removed from the board, giving the hero a 4:1 chance to kill the monster. Right?

Comment: I think a lot of that is going to depend on the details of the haunt. Also there is no need to spoiler which haunt you as that doesn't really reveal much information

Comment: It reveals that in haunt 46, monsters die instead of get stunned, which is information only found in the traitor-book, not in the hero-book, and the info is not especially needed to solve the question (unless one wouldn't believe me and wanted to look it up) so I thought better safe than sorry.

Comment: That is the information you should spoiler, not the haunt itself. Monsters dying in a single hit is a spoiler regardless of what haunt it happens in while knowing what haunt is being played should never be a spoiler.

Comment: But that is my question: is it correct that monsters die in a single hit, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: You can put spoilers around that part of the question so that people who don't want the spoiler can still read the question without having it spoiled. By just putting the haunt number behind the spoiler tag you are not preventing anything from being spoiled at all. In fact with your question title as it is you spoil that mechanic of the haunt without the reader even needing to click into the question to see what haunt it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at page 18 of the Rulebook there's a section of **How Monsters Work** which says:

> **Monsters can't be killed.**. If a monster would take any damage, it is **stunned** and misses its next turn... Stunned monsters can't slow an explorer's movement. Even if a haunt says to do something other than stun monsters when they take damage, they can still be stunned by effects that specifically stun monsters.

These are the base rules for monsters which can be manipulated by specific haunt rules. Do note that the Traitor may know game altering rules that you, as a Hero, simply do not know.

Now, let's take a look specifically at **Haunt 46**:
*Below are minor spoilers for Haunt 46 including special rules. It is brief and only outlines the rules in question. Read at your own risk!*

> **The Feast!**
>  Cannibal Freaks ( Speed 2, Might 4, Sanity 4 )
> **Special Rules:**
>  If a Cannibal Freak is defeated by an attack, it's killed instead of stunned.
>  In this scenario the special rules dictate that instead of getting stunned the monster would be defeated instead. That is if they take any mental or physical damage. That being said, specific items that stun can still be used to incapacitate the monster. The monsters will die in one hit but the base stats for the monsters are also fairly high. Depending on how many items the Heros were able to attain during the game you may need to play this safe and cluster your monsters together or corner a specific hero to get them out of the game.

Do note not all Haunts are perfectly balanced and some rules may not be flushed out enough to answer every single question that may pop up. From Avalon Hill:

> Keep in mind if the rules are not specified in the rulebook you and your group can decide what makes the game most fun.

In this case though, I think the answer is cut and dry.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Monsters are OKish statwise (speed 2 might 4 san 4) but most heroes easily have 4+ might, making this haunt very tough for the monsters imho.

Comment: @Konerak There's really nothing absolutely true about what heroes will have when a haunt starts. It's actually possible (though unlikely) for a haunt to start on the first turn of the first player, with the players having nothing but the omen card that triggered the haunt. Some haunts are easier early on and harder later (larger house making it harder), some are harder early on and easier later (lower stats, lack of stuff making it harder)